# No results from MSGraph when attempting to retrieve anything using bearer token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, spfx

I'm attempting to get anything from MSGraph using a bearer token: emails, events etc.
I have:

1. Made sure the app has the permissions to do whatever it needs to.
2. Tested without using a token to get my emails and SharePoint list items and this works.
3. Tested the token on Postman and it works successfully to get what I need USING the token.
   It's just that the code does NOT work:

Here is the function that successfully gets a token and following that, the function that retrieves the events:

```
  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IMsGraphTestProps> = React.createElement(
      MsGraphTest,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        hasTeamsContext: !!this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams,
        userDisplayName: this.context.pageContext.user.displayName,
        context: this.context,
        msGraphClientFactory: this.context.msGraphClientFactory,

      }
    );
    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);

export const TOKEN_API: string = "https://graph.microsoft.com";

let tokenProvider: AadTokenProvider;
let client: MSGraphClientV3;

import { AadTokenProvider, MSGraphClientV3 } from "@microsoft/sp-http";

export const getToken = async (msGraphcontext: any): Promise<string> => {
  try {
    tokenProvider = await msGraphcontext.aadTokenProviderFactory.getTokenProvider();
    const accessToken: string = await tokenProvider.getToken(_.TOKEN_API, false);
    return `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('getToken:=> ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    throw (err);
  }
}

export const retrieveEvents = async (msGraphcontext: any) => {
  try {
    const token = await getToken(msGraphcontext);
    return await client.api('/me/events').headers({
        'Authorization': `${token}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'

    }).get()
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err, 'err');
  }
};
```

This successfully retrieves emails but doesn't use a token:

```
export const getEmailsMsGraph = async (msGraphcontext: any): Promise<any> => {
  let emails: any[] = [];

  return await msGraphcontext.msGraphClientFactory
    .getClient('3')
    .then(async (client: MSGraphClientV3) => {
      await client
        .api('/me/messages')
        .top(5)
        .orderby("receivedDateTime desc")
        .get((error, messages: any, rawResponse?: any) => {
          emails = messages.value;
        });
      return emails;
    });
};
```

Can anyone see something wrong with what I'm doing. Please note, that the token is valid but I receive just `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'api')` from the console.

Comment: Not sure how your point 2.) is supposed to make any sense, how could this possibly work if you _don't_ supply a token? The error message sounds like `client` wasn't actually defined (or what line is that actually referring to?)

Comment: It's possibly due to my inexperience working with MSGraph - I've added a function that does work in the OP. The line that it's referring to is in ```retrieveEvents()``` the ```Client.api``` line  I believe.

Comment: You might not _explicitly_ pass a token there, but I am sure that the request still uses one in the background - everything else would not make _any_ sense - without a token, the API would not know who `/me` is supposed to be in the first place, and if it returned _anyone's_ emails without any token, that would be a huge privacy hole in their API.

Comment: _"The line that it's referring to is in retrieveEvents() the Client.api line I believe."_ - I can't tell, based on those snippets, where `client` is supposed to come from to begin with, or in what scope it might exist. Not sure if `msGraphcontext.msGraphClientFactory.getClient('3')` somehow creates it in the current scope (if that is even possible)?

Comment: I've added everything I can think of, including how MSGraph is being initialised in context with the app, how it's being imported and initialised in the function.

Comment: What do you get with `console.log(client);` before the line that throws the error?

Comment: undefined for client. How am I supposed to initialise it?

Comment: Dunno, can't you just use the same syntax as in your last code block, which works? `await msGraphcontext.msGraphClientFactory.getClient('3').then(...)`